# How can I alias specific graphql request in Cypress?

Tags: graphql, cypress

Firstly, it is not duplication of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814647/how-can-i-alias-specific-graphql-requests-in-cypress). This question shows specific graphql request could be handled by `operationName` because it is unique in author's situation like below.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/graphql', req => {
  if (req.body.operationName === 'MyCustomOperation') {
    req.alias = 'MyCustomOperation';
  }
});
cy.wait('@MyCustomOperation');
```

By above method, I can wait specific graphql request if every request are differentiated with `operationName`. However, it has edge case when same operations have different variables.

For example, I have same 5 requests called `GetRole` query. Each request has variable `{ name: 'john' }`, `{ name: 'bob' }`, ...etc. It means that like below.

- `GetRole({ variables: { name: 'john' }})`
- `GetRole({ variables: { name: 'bob' }})`
- ....

In accordance with [this description](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3083#issuecomment-611733805), graphql requests were grouped randomly if each request has same alias. This case is applied to above 5 requests because each request has same alias called `GetRole` even if each request has different variables.

In this situation,  how can I separate each request based on variables? I used method below.

```js
const aliasList: string[] = [];
cy.intercept('POST', '/graphql', req => {
  const randomString = generateRandom(); // some random generation function
  if (req.body.operationName === 'MyCustomOperation') {
    const alias = `MyCustomOperation${randomString}`;
    alisList.push(alias);
    req.alias = alias;
  }
});
aliasList.forEach(alias => cy.wait(`@${alias}`));
```

But, it doesn't work as expected because `aliasList` is empty when I use `cy.wait()`. I also used `then()` to `cy.intercept` but also doesn't work too.

How can I handle this problem? I have to wait every graphql requests independently.

Thanks for your reading!