# Cypress: global variables in callbacks

Tags: cypress

I am trying to set up a new Cypress framework and I hit a point where I need help.

The scenario I am trying to work out: a page that is calling the same endpoint after every change and I use an interceptor to wait for the call. As we all know you can’t use the same intercept name for the same request multiple times so I did a trick here. I used a dynamically named alias, which works.

```
var counters = {}
function registerIntercept(method, url, name) {
   counters[name] = 1;
   cy.intercept(method, url, (req) => {
      var currentCounter = counters[name]++;
      cy.wrap(counters).as(counters)
      req.alias = name + (currentCounter);

   })
}

function waitForCall(call) {
   waitForCall_(call + (counters[call.substr(1)])); 
// HERE counters[any_previously_added_key] is always 1, even though the counters entry in registerIntercept is bigger
// I suspect counters here is not using the same counters value as registerIntercept

}

function waitForCall_(call) {
   cy.wait(call)
   cy.wait(100)
}
```

It is supposed to be used by using `waitForCall(“@callalias”)` and it will be converted to @callalias1, callalias2 and so on.

The problem is that the global counters is working in registerIntercept but I can’t get its values from waitForCall. It will always retrieve value 1 for a specific key, while the counters key in registerIntercept is already at a bigger number.

This code works if you use it as `waitForCall_(“@callalias4”)` to wait for the 4th request for example.  Each intercept will get an alias ending with an incremented number. But I want to not keep track of how many calls were made and let the code retrieve that from counters and build the wait.

Any idea why counters in waitForCall is not having the same values for its keys as it has in registerIntercept?

Comment: Have a look a this thread. When using GraphQL, each API call uses the same endpoint. You might find something useful for your framework. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814647/how-can-i-alias-specific-graphql-requests-in-cypress